# Как расшифровать входящий\исходящий трафик

Tags: tcp, wireshark, трафик

С помощью WireShark нахожу нужный мне пакет,и не знаю **как посмотреть передаваемые\получаемые данные TCP пакета?** Вероятно, они зашифрованы, только вот каким способом не знаю. Бьюсь над этим уже несколько дней.

Это пакеты из онлайн-игры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Тут в чат было отправлено сообщение `privetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivetprivet`

Как правило в этой игре используется шифрование `Base64` выяснилось из файлов игры, но тут может быть применён и другой способ шифрования

```
Frame 19: 228 bytes on wire (1824 bits), 228 bytes captured (1824 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0B176104-3CF0-4B28-9654-27495506A6B6}, id 0
    Section number: 1
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{0B176104-3CF0-4B28-9654-27495506A6B6})
        Interface name: \Device\NPF_{0B176104-3CF0-4B28-9654-27495506A6B6}
        Interface description: Беспроводная сеть
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Sep  5, 2023 13:06:24.633138000 RTZ 4 (зима)
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1693901184.633138000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.002167000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.002167000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 1.911848000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 19
    Frame Length: 228 bytes (1824 bits)
    Capture Length: 228 bytes (1824 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:data]
    [Coloring Rule Name: TCP]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp]
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_e9:23:55 (d8:0d:17:e9:23:55), Dst: IntelCor_5b:22:0a (4c:1d:96:5b:22:0a)
    Destination: IntelCor_5b:22:0a (4c:1d:96:5b:22:0a)
    Source: Tp-LinkT_e9:23:55 (d8:0d:17:e9:23:55)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.67.207.121, Dst: 192.168.0.101
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x70 (DSCP: AF32, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0111 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Assured Forwarding 32 (28)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 214
    Identification: 0x79ac (31148)
    010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 56
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header Checksum: 0x8b3b [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source Address: 172.67.207.121
    Destination Address: 192.168.0.101
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 2052, Dst Port: 51074, Seq: 78, Ack: 263, Len: 174
    Source Port: 2052
    Destination Port: 51074
    [Stream index: 0]
    [Conversation completeness: Incomplete (12)]
    [TCP Segment Len: 174]
    Sequence Number: 78    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 3334247682
    [Next Sequence Number: 252    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 263    (relative ack number)
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 3021116392
    0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Accurate ECN: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced: Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: ·······AP···]
    Window: 9
    [Calculated window size: 9]
    [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
    Checksum: 0x3b37 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent Pointer: 0
    [Timestamps]
        [Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 1.911848000 seconds]
        [Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.002167000 seconds]
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [Bytes in flight: 187]
        [Bytes sent since last PSH flag: 174]
    TCP payload (174 bytes)
Data (174 bytes)
    Data: 827e00aa646174612c35333939302c009f80000000082f08861e6b1443ed8e856d2b29e8…
    [Payload MD5 hash: 56db6ecdc89c127160b69addadadea74]
    [Length: 174]
```

```
0000   4c 1d 96 5b 22 0a d8 0d 17 e9 23 55 08 00 45 70   L..[".....#U..Ep
0010   00 d6 79 ac 40 00 38 06 8b 3b ac 43 cf 79 c0 a8   ..y.@.8..;.C.y..
0020   00 65 08 04 c7 82 c6 bc 95 02 b4 12 93 e8 50 18   .e............P.
0030   00 09 3b 37 00 00 82 7e 00 aa 64 61 74 61 2c 35   ..;7...~..data,5
0040   33 39 39 30 2c 00 9f 80 00 00 00 08 2f 08 86 1e   3990,......./...
0050   6b 14 43 ed 8e 85 6d 2b 29 e8 70 25 90 3f d4 ed   k.C...m+).p%.?..
0060   8e 85 6d 2b 29 e8 70 25 90 3f d4 ec 60 05 4d 2f   ..m+).p%.?..`.M/
0070   f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05   ..`.M/..`.M/..`.
0080   4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec   M/..`.M/..`.M/..
0090   60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f   `.M/..`.M/..`.M/
00a0   f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05   ..`.M/..`.M/..`.
00b0   4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec   M/..`.M/..`.M/..
00c0   60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f   `.M/..`.M/..`.M/
00d0   f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05 4d 2f f4 ec 60 05   ..`.M/..`.M/..`.
00e0   4d 2f f4 0c                                       M/..
```

Comment: Ну если там почему-то торчит `data,12362,` голым текстом, то вряд ли оно зашифровано. А что всё это означает — читайте в документации игры или выясняйте методом проб и ошибок

Comment: Ну а тот факт, что IP-адрес отправителя принадлежит Cloudflare, даёт понять, что в качестве транспортного протокола здесь используется WebSocket, и весь этот пакет содержит в себе binary frame размером 159 байт. Только вот что эти 159 байт означают, вам всё равно никто кроме разработчиков игры рассказать не сможет

Comment: Вы хотя бы трейс приложили бы к вопросу.

Comment: Немного обновил вопрос.

Comment: Могу приложить файл Wireshark, если нужно

Comment: @andreymal не совсем понял взаимосвязь "Cloudflare = websocket", но если это он, есть смысл в него постучаться, возможно после handshake про формат намекнёт.

Comment: При декодировании через WebSocket хорошо просматриваются Пинги, репорты, системная информация (после просмотра немаскированных данных). Само сообщение зашифровано. В вопросе уже unmasked данные